# Laravel 9 unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, crud, laravel-9

Here is update below and its unit test which I created. when I run the test I get the following error:
"Expected response status code [200] but received 404. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404."
Can you help me please ?
In my controller:

```
 /** @var \App\Models\Transaction */
    $previousTrans = Transaction::whereNroTransaction($request->input('transaction_id'))->first();

    if (is_null($previousTrans)) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Transaction Not Found'
        ], 404);
    }

    $cancelingTrans = $previousTrans->replicate([
        'NroTransaction',
        'FechaTrans',
        'EstPrisEnCompte',
        'Msg_error',
        'NumTrans_cancel',
        'CanalTransaction'
    ]);

    $cancelingTrans->fill([
        'NumTel'        => $request->input('msisdn'),
        'observ'        => $request->input('observation'),
        'TipoTrans'     => 9
    ]);

    if ($cancelingTrans->save()) {
        return new TransactionResource($cancelingTrans);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Could not cancel the deposit'
    ], 500);
```

Here is my unit test:

```
 public function test_deposit_canceled()
{
    

    $deposit = Transaction::factory()->create([
                                    'NumTel' => '22899999999',
                                    'observ' => 'first'
                                    ]);

    $this->putJson("api/deposits/{$deposit->id}", [
                                    'NumTel' => '22900000000',
                                    'observ' => 'Second'
                                    ])
         ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

My routing:

```
Route::put('deposits/{deposits}/cancel', [DepositController::class, 'update']);
```

Comment: When calling the api shouldn't you start with a forward slash e.g `/api`?

Comment: @Cyclonecode Laravel 9 understands this without worries

Comment: Ok, but looking on the test you are not calling your route above?

Comment: @Cyclonecode that's what I don't understand. I still added /api to see

Answer (score 0):

In your test you are using the route `api/deposits/{$deposit->id}`, while you have declared the route as:

```
Route::put('deposits/{deposits}/cancel', [DepositController::class, 'update']);
```

So I am guessing you need to update your actual call to:

```
$this->putJson("api/deposits/{$deposit->id}/cancel", [
                                'NumTel' => '22900000000',
                                'observ' => 'Second'
                               ])
     ->assertStatus(200);
```

I am also a little bit confused why you are not registering the route suffixing it with `api` e.g:

```
Route::put('api/deposits/{deposits}/cancel', [DepositController::class, 'update']);
```

But maybe this is something that laravel handles for you?